# Bluetooth LE - L2CAP CO Channel on android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, l2cap

I'm trying to connect an android device to an embedded control unit via L2CAP CO (Connection Oriented) with Bluetooth LE. 
Apple created in iOS a new function to create a custom L2CAP Channel https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbl2capchannel to a peripheral and avoid the usage of a GATT Server communication.

My question is: Is there any future or currently implementation in android to have the same functionality as iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Android Q will provide official support](https://developer.android.com/preview/features#bluetooth-le-coc):

> #### Bluetooth LE Connection Oriented Channels (CoC)
>
> Android Q enables your app to use BLE CoC connections to transfer larger data streams between two BLE devices. This interface abstracts Bluetooth and connectivity mechanics to simplify implementation.

Comment: Think the link is update to current version so no use, I think here is the exact link of what @EnderX trying to add in his answer ( https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/features#bluetooth-le-coc )